# Is it correct BIND9 configuration for my external DNS zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, ns-record, named-conf

My file with zone

My `/etc/bind/db.piduna.org`

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN piduna.org.
@       IN      SOA     ns1.piduna.org. root.piduna.org. (
                     2018031701         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.piduna.org.
@       IN      NS      ns2.piduna.org.
@       IN      A       192.168.110.15

ns1     IN      A       192.168.110.15
ns2     IN      A       192.168.110.14

abc100  IN      A       192.168.110.1
abc101  IN      A       192.168.110.2
abc102  IN      A       192.168.110.3
abc103  IN      A       192.168.110.4
abc104  IN      A       192.168.110.5
abc105  IN      A       192.168.110.6
abc106  IN      A       192.168.110.7
abc107  IN      A       192.168.110.8
abc108  IN      A       192.168.110.9
abc109  IN      A       192.168.110.10
abc110  IN      A       192.168.110.11
abc111  IN      A       192.168.110.12
abc112  IN      A       192.168.110.13
abc113  IN      A       192.168.110.14
abc114  IN      A       192.168.110.15

gitlab  IN      A       192.168.110.14
redmine IN      A       192.168.110.14

*       IN      CNAME   piduna.org.
```

`192.168.110.*` of course is not real ip addresses. instead them i am using real ip addresses of vps-s.

My `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "abchosting.org" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/db.piduna.org";
};
```

My `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        listen-on port 53 {
        127.0.0.1;
        192.168.110.15;
        };

        forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
        };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { none; };
};
```

So, i have tested it. Everything is ok. Works. But i have doubts about my configuration of  `/etc/bind/db.piduna.org`. Is everything is ok. Maybe some advices according to security ? I am repeating, i made this for external domain. I need:
- 15 A-records for my vps-s;
- two A-records for my services, like gitlab and redmine;
- ping sub-domain from 192.168.110.15
Thanks for your understanding and help.

Comment: Use RFC5737 when you want to obfuscate IP addresses

Comment: you are going to have issues when you say that for the zone `abchosting.org` you are serving up a zone file that specifies `piduna.org`.  Note that you can check named.conf* syntax wtih `named-checkconf` and zone file syntax with `named-checkzone example.com /path/to/zone/file/for/example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You say you have tested it, so what did you do exaclty? `named-checkzone`? Any kind of online troubleshooting tool?

What are you doubts? Your question is too broad. What security do you talk about?

I see various problems though:

- you are using a wildcard record. Do you really need it? If not, I recommend to remove it as it creates far more problems than solutions
- so you seem to have an authoritative nameserver since you define a zone, but it listens only on local/internal IP addresses. Does that mean it is not globally reachable (which would be a bad idea for an authoritative nameserver) or you have some NAT setup in front of it, which is also a very bad idea for a nameserver?
- so you seem to have an authoritative nameserver, but you forward queries externally. It seems you mix recursive and authoritative functions in the same server, which is a very bad idea security-wise (and one could also say that in any case forwarding to Google Public DNS is not a good idea security-wise, you should have your own local recursive nameserver)

Comment: 1) yes, i need wildcard, because i will use for hosting this.
2) 192.168.110.* means not local address, i have external instead these ip addreses, i just not wrote them, because i don't want to show pool with my external ip-s

Comment: This is exactly why you should choose RFC5737 when you obfuscate IP addresses instead of using IPs used for something else as defined in RFC1918

Comment: And you can do hosting without a DNS wildcard.